# "expect" in bash to input password

Tags: ssh, bash

I'm trying to find a way to automatically enter a password when starting an SSH session. 
Is there a way to do that?
I'm using openssh on Win10 to connect to my remote server.

Thank you

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered using SSH keys instead of passwords?  This would solve your problem, unless you're required to use the password.

Answer (score 2):

Migrate off of passwords to ssh keys. Consider storing passphrases for these in `ssh-agent`.

If you must automate a password, use the `sshpass` program. It has less insecure options like reading from environment variables or pipes, and tricks ssh's TTY check for you.